# How Create XML on Client, then finish it on Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have tables "Clients" and "ORDERS" on server.
I have a task to create XML file, with information about client, and send it to server. Then on server i should find all orders of that client, finish XML with that information and send XML file back to client.
I do not not how to create xml on client and finish it on server. How do i do it?
Need to do it using C#

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. As it stands your question is not a 
"Good Fit" for this site. Your question needs to be more related to a specific issue with some associated code. At the moment your are dealing with broad concepts, which is not what this site is  targeted at. Please read the Help, FAQ, and Tour pages to get a better understanding of the sort of questions that work best here.

Comment: Each message between client and server is independent. So in your case the client(s) create an XML message.  The server creates an XML and then adds nodes from the client(s).  Finally the server sends back to client a new combined XML message.